# Streaming input to System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine

Tags: c#, sockets, streaming, speech-recognition, sapi

I am trying to do "streaming" speech recognition in C# from a TCP socket. The problem I am having is that SpeechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToAudioStream() seems to require a Stream of a defined length which can seek. Right now the only way I can think to make this work is to repeatedly run the recognizer on a MemoryStream as more input comes in.

Here's some code to illustrate:

```
            SpeechRecognitionEngine appRecognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

            System.Speech.AudioFormat.SpeechAudioFormatInfo formatInfo = new System.Speech.AudioFormat.SpeechAudioFormatInfo(8000, System.Speech.AudioFormat.AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, System.Speech.AudioFormat.AudioChannel.Mono);

            NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(socket,true);
            appRecognizer.SetInputToAudioStream(stream, formatInfo);
            // At the line above a "NotSupportedException" complaining that "This stream does not support seek operations."
```

Does anyone know how to get around this? It must support streaming input of some sort, since it works fine with the microphone using SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice().

Thanks, Sean

Answer (score 16):

I got live speech recognition working by overriding the stream class:

```
class SpeechStreamer : Stream
{
    private AutoResetEvent _writeEvent;
    private List<byte> _buffer;
    private int _buffersize;
    private int _readposition;
    private int _writeposition;
    private bool _reset;

    public SpeechStreamer(int bufferSize)
    {
        _writeEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
         _buffersize = bufferSize;
         _buffer = new List<byte>(_buffersize);
         for (int i = 0; i < _buffersize;i++ )
             _buffer.Add(new byte());
        _readposition = 0;
        _writeposition = 0;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return -1L; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return 0L; }
        set {  }
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return 0L;
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {

    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i<count && _writeEvent!=null)
        {
            if (!_reset && _readposition >= _writeposition)
            {
                _writeEvent.WaitOne(100, true);
                continue;
            }
            buffer[i] = _buffer[_readposition+offset];
            _readposition++;
            if (_readposition == _buffersize)
            {
                _readposition = 0;
                _reset = false;
            }
            i++;
        }

        return count;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        for (int i = offset; i < offset+count; i++)
        {
            _buffer[_writeposition] = buffer[i];
            _writeposition++;
            if (_writeposition == _buffersize)
            {
                _writeposition = 0;
                _reset = true;
            }
        }
        _writeEvent.Set();

    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        _writeEvent.Close();
        _writeEvent = null;
        base.Close();
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {

    }
}
```

... and using an instance of that as the stream input to the SetInputToAudioStream method. As soon as the stream returns a length or the returned count is less than that requested the recognition engine thinks the input has finished. This sets up a circular buffer that never finishes.

Comment: @Sean hey, could you please give me a pointer on how to use this class? It seems really promising and I would love to use it. But how do I set it to use an existing Stream?

Comment: @Monacraft just read from your existing stream and write into this one

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wrapping the network stream in a System.IO.BufferedStream?

```
NetworkStream netStream = new NetworkStream(socket,true);
BufferedStream buffStream = new BufferedStream(netStream, 8000*16*1); // buffers 1 second worth of data
appRecognizer.SetInputToAudioStream(buffStream, formatInfo);
```

Comment: Did you verify that the buffered stream supported seeking?  

I.e., in the above code, does buffStream.CanSeek() return true?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it can't be done ("By design"!).  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/fcf62d6d-19df-4ca9-9f1f-17724441f84e

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution.

```
class FakeStreamer : Stream
{
    public bool bExit = false;
    Stream stream;
    TcpClient client;
    public FakeStreamer(TcpClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.stream = client.GetStream();
        this.stream.ReadTimeout = 100; //100ms
    }
    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return stream.CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return stream.CanWrite; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return -1L; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return 0L; }
        set { }
    }
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return 0L;
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        stream.SetLength(value);
    }
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int len = 0, c = count;
        while (c > 0 && !bExit)
        {
            try
            {
                len = stream.Read(buffer, offset, c);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.HResult == -2146232800) // Timeout
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Exit read loop
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!client.Connected || len == 0)
            {
                //Exit read loop
                return 0;
            }
            offset += len;
            c -= len;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        stream.Write(buffer,offset,count);
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        stream.Close();
        base.Close();
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        stream.Flush();
    }
}
```

How to Use:

```
//client connect in
TcpClient clientSocket = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
FakeStreamer buffStream = new FakeStreamer(clientSocket);
...
//recognizer init
m_recognizer.SetInputToAudioStream(buffStream , audioFormat);
...
//recognizer end
if (buffStream != null)
    buffStream.bExit = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up buffering the input and then sending it to the speech recognition engine in successively larger chunks. For instance, I might send at first the first 0.25 seconds, then the first 0.5 seconds, then the first 0.75 seconds, and so on until I get a result. I am not sure if this is the most efficient way of going about this, but it yields satisfactory results for me.

Best of luck, Sean